# my customuser (AbstractBaseUser) is not creating table in postgres and django rest framework

Tags: django, postgresql, serialization, django-rest-framework, migration

my CustomUser table is not being created in dbms
when doing migrations it tell all ok but when running the project and going to api it fails to fetch dbms table

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# Create your models here.



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    



    # Add more fields as needed
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    UserName = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100, unique=True)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    ContactNumber = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    CompanyRole = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)


    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
```

and when running this it show

> "ProgrammingError at /hrms/api/users/
>
> relation "hrms_customuser" does not exist LINE 1: ..."is_staff",
> "hrms_customuser"."is_superuser" FROM "hrms_cust..."

Comment: You should make migrations and migrate.

Comment: its already done but i doesn't show any change in table